# How to set time in Linux by Bash that not change after reboot?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to code a bash script that set Time and Date manually, this work but after reboot my system (Ubuntu 18.04) time and date resets to automatic mode. How I can write a bash for set time/date that not change after reboot?

My try as a beginner ended to this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# A simple bash script to set system date & time
timedatectl set-ntp 0
date +%Y%m%d -s $1
date +%T -s $2":00"
```

Comment: Sync the time with an NTP server. [link](https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-synchronize-time-with-ntp-server-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-xubuntu-debian/) . Then make sure your timezone is correct. And you're done.

Comment: What *is* the time after you reboot? Either some boot-time script is setting the clock, or (less likely) your hardware itself is not saving/maintaining the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timedatectl set-ntp 0 && timedatectl set-time 'HH:MM:SS'` will turn off web clock sync and let you update it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its change after rebooting same as my solution.

Comment: Insert this lines in a bash script, put your script in `/etc/init.d`, owned by root and do `chmod +x <file>`. It will apply these settings each time your pc starts.

Comment: This solution not good idea, because i need a script that an user can set time and change time

Answer (score 0):

I done it by using Hard Ware Clock.